# I didn't get 4 outbreak packs for free

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

Operation Chimera in Rainbow 6: Siege was just released and I saw a lot of posts about getting Ash's elite skin and 4 outbreak packs for free.

The thing is, after I logged in and got into the game, I didn't get any of them. I restarted the game and tried everything, still no answer.

What is wrong with my game?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/82fnn1/year_3_season_1_known_issues_list/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Sidewinder Elite Skin and Outbreak Packs were held back by distribution bugs, and should arrive March 7th 2018 or “soon” thereafter.

Both of the Elite skin and Packs seem to be experiencing an issue where players simply aren't receiving them. Ubisoft investigated and is resolving both cases and has [**an official Reddit thread for keeping watch on their status**](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/82fnn1/year_3_season_1_known_issues_list/). Keep an eye on that thread.

### Four Outbreak packs: Fix being deployed, they should arrive today.

As originally reported [on Ubisoft's twitter](https://twitter.com/Rainbow6Game/status/971107324873072640) (6th March):

> We are aware that some players did not receive their 4 free Outbreak Packs during the outage. We are investigating, and will update you when we have more info.
>
> For a list of known issues, please refer to the thread here: http://www.reddit.com/82fnn1/

### Ash's Sidewinder Elite Skin: Fix being deployed, should arrive “soon”.

Ubisoft [confirmed on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Rainbow6Game/status/971075448108175362) (6th March) they've removed the skin temporarily and are working on a bug with distributing it:

> The Ash Sidewinder Elite is being removed from the shop while we actively work on the fix to get it to all players that qualified to receive it for free.
>
> Ash's Black Viper Elite, from the Outbreak Collection, is still available through Outbreak Packs.

The Reddit thread says they've found a fix for the issue and are working on getting it out.

Comment: Thank you very much I am happy to say that both outbreak packs and ash elite skin arrived

Answer (score 2):

Ubisoft is working on the Ash elite skin, they removed it for now, but that will be fixed.
I don't know what's wrong with the packs, I restarted my ps4 a couple times but it doesn't seem to work.

https://twitter.com/Rainbow6Game/status/971107324873072640?s=20

https://twitter.com/Rainbow6Game/status/971075448108175362?s=20

Comment: Could you add some citation to clarify the Ash skin is disabled for now?

Comment: https://twitter.com/Rainbow6Game/status/971075448108175362?s=20

Comment: Thanks, I've updated this. Looks like we both found those tweets. +1

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Feel free to take a [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) or visit the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) for more information, thanks for improving your answer to cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

Reddit has the answer. From the bugs thread:

> Some players are not receiving 4 free Outbreak packs - We are investigating

https://www.reddit.com/r/Rainbow6/comments/82fnn1/year_3_season_1_known_issues_list/